# Замедляет ли проверка на уникальность пары столбцов (индекс) добавление в таблицу?

Tags: mysql

У нас есть таблица, в которой содержатся посещения всех страниц каждым пользователем, и иногда в неё нужно внести порядка 1000 записей в минуту.

Если в таблице установлен индекс `PRIMARY KEY (user_id, post_id)`, то будет ли снижение производительности при, допустим, 500.000 записей, из-за поиска уже существующих совпадений при добавлении?

Я планировал добавлять записи без индекса, и планово чистить дубли каждые несколько минут плановой задачей, но, думаю, что это очевидный костыль.

Comment: Проверка по индексу на дублирование при вставке - несомненно более производительное решение, чем пакетное удаление по расписанию. *иногда в неё нужно внести порядка 1000 записей в минуту.* 17 инсертов в секунду - это вообще ни о чём.